# Django using __init__ method in classes extending (admin.ModelAdmin)

Tags: django, python-3.x, init, modeladmin

I am fairly new to Django.

I have an `admin.Models` extended class that's pretty typical (has `list_display`, `search_fields`, etc).

It looks something like this:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'all',
        'my',
        'things',
    )
    ...
admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```

My problem is that this `ModelAdmin` loads somethings from a model with something like `foo_list = Foo.objects.filter(group__name='something')`.

Because this is a heavy task, I'd like to do it **once** on initialization, and then use the same thing over and over again when specifying custom `"_field"` functions.

My thoughts are to do this in the `__init__` method of this class, but when implement my own constructor, it doesn't register with Django as a url; i.e.

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    list_display = (
        'all',
        'my',
        'things',
    )
    ...
# This register portion removed.
# admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```

The above will "build" correctly and run, but attempting to visit the site says the URL is not found (not surprising since I removed the register part).

However, when I add the register portion back in, I get a message about a misuse of my constructor, i.e adding back the `admin.site.register` and running `python manage.py runserver ...` results in something like:

```
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

I've taken this constructor from [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956332/how-do-you-load-a-custom-field-in-django) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956332/how-do-you-load-a-custom-field-in-django) [to](http://marcelchastain.com/2018/05/getting-access-to-request-in-django-modeladmin/) [no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26959934/use-a-form-with-a-custom-init-in-django-admin) [avail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000950/how-to-set-initial-data-for-django-admin-model-add-instance-form), so I'm not sure if this is a Django versioning thing or not.

**My questions are:**

1. **How can I use an initialization method or some kind of "lifecycle-hook" in an `admin.ModelAdmin` extended class?**
2. **Why does implemented my constructor break the constructors interface when registering the URL?**

This is my environment:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.4 (default, Sep  7 2019, 18:29:04)
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> django.VERSION
(2, 2, 5, 'final', 0)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Your init function is just wrong; as the error says, you need to use the correct type - FooAdmin, not Foo. I'm not sure of the relevance of the bit about removing the register; without that, the class is never instantiated.

Comment: Thanks. That was it. I was sure other examples were using the model. I might be stupid.