# Django custome admin dropdown from property in model

Tags: python, django

In my model I have a getter and setter for a property:

```
class SomeModel(ext_models.TimeStampedModel):
    ...

    @property
    def test_field(self):
        return {'key1': 'val1', 'key2': 'val2'}

    @test_field.setter
    def test_field(self, value):
        print(value)
```

I'd like to use the `test_field` in the admin as a dropdown. 
I have tried to add it in the `fieldsets`, but I receive the error

```
Unknown field(s) test_field specified
```

I have also added it to the `readonly_fields` and then the field is at least displayed, however just a string and  not editable of course.

Is there a nice way to get a simple dropdown widget displaying the dict?

Comment: What do you mean, "as a selector"? A selector for what, where?

Comment: I want a selector in the admin with the values from the property `test_field`

Comment: @DanielRoseman sorry I used the wrong term, I meant dropdown

Comment: But the question is what should happen when selecting an option from the dropdown? What are you trying to achieve? And is this in the admin 'change' view or the admin 'list' view?

Comment: It is the admin change view; when a new value in the dropdown is selected (and saved) the setter of the propterty should be triggered to perform a custom handling

Comment: You can only edit model fields in the admin change view. Since `test_field` isn't a model field, that won't work. You need to override the `ModelForm` for this view and add this field to it, handling validation and saving of it in your form. See for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948018/django-admin-add-custom-form-fields-that-are-not-part-of-the-model)