# Creating Custom Display Fields in Django Admin (that don't exist in models.py)

Tags: django, django-admin

I have two fields in `models.py`

```
numberOfUsers = IntegerField()
numberOfUserCredits = IntegerField()
```

In Django admin, instead of viewing two columns with

`list_display = ['numberOfUsers', 'numberOfUserCredits']`

I'd like to instead clean this up a bit and concatenate these two fields for simpler viewing:

`str(numberOfUsers) + '/' + str(numberOfUserCredits)`

How can I create a custom field like this in Django admin? I could create a new field in `models.py` that creates this field automatically on model save, but I am wondering if there is an easier way to go about doing this.

---

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17948018/django-admin-add-custom-form-fields-that-are-not-part-of-the-model?rq=1) already asked, but the answer below was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add it to your ModelAdmin class something like following, also i would suggest using [f strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) instead of concatenation

```
class SomeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (..., 'user_field')

    def user_field(self, obj):
        return f'{obj.numberOfUsers}/{obj.numberOfUserCredits}'
    user_field.short_description = 'userShort'
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!